# How to install specific version of Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I want to install a specific version of Visual Studio, but don't know how, specifically version 17.0. All my search result is just release notes, can't install. How to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I see it, we are only able to rollback to earlier version if using Enterprise or Professional licence ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#updating-your-installation-to-a-specific-release)),  in my case, I'm using Community, which is free. Sad :(

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install a specific version of visual studio , Download from below link.

To go back to an earlier release, you must uninstall your current installation and use below link to download and re-install the version that you prefer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#updating-your-installation-to-a-specific-release

Comment: It's worth noting that this is specifically for VS Pro and Enterprise editions only

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to update to a particular version of VS Community. While the GUI installer does not seem to be able to select one, it is possible to point it to a particular version through the command line. It is however quite complicated, more than it needs to be honestly:

- Locate the particular version in the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=visual%20studio%202022) and download the installer.
- When I ran the installer, it extracted something, then close, and nothing happened. In any case, navigate to the `%TEMP%` folder where the installer extracts its files. If it closes without doing anything, it also deletes the temporary extracted folder, but you have time to copy it somewhere to look inside.
- Find the `ChannelManifest.json` file. Should be about 90 KiB.
- Upload it to a web server so that you have a URI it could be downloaded from, say `https://example.org/ChannelManifest.json`.
- Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` and open the command line there.
- Run `setup update --channelId VisualStudio.17.Release --productId Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community --channelURI "https://example.org/ChannelManifest.json"`. Feel free to add [other parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).
- Existing installation of VS Community 2022 should start updating to the specified version.